# Running Gradle plugin directly from command line

Tags: gradle

In Maven, if I wanted to analyze my project with sonar, I could do:

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

using the 'short' plugin name and goal.

In Gradle, is there a similar way to run plugins, **without** declaring them in the `build.gradle` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently, but there will be at some point. What you can do is to apply the plugin out-of-band (in some `init.gradle`).

Comment: When you mean "out-of-band," I would apply some other build script inside my `build.gradle` as well? Isn't that just adding indirection, but not really keeping it out of the main process? Sorry, I'm much more used to Maven.

Comment: With out-of-band I meant that you don't have to touch any of the build's own build scripts, but can add an `init.gradle` in your user home or as a command line parameter (`--init-script init.gradle`). I thought this is maybe what you are after.

Comment: Aha, I see -- I didn't know about `--init-script.`

Comment: As this answer is from 2013, anyone know if this is possible in a simpler way now? This method will probably work for us but it would be nice to know if a cleaner way exists.

Comment: Still no answers?

Comment: Apparently it was discussed a while ago in here (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1870) but it was closed with no real reason. It doesn't make any sense not to have this, when an older tool like Maven is able to do it easily. I guess I will have to use an init.gradle file... So ugly.

Answer (score 4):

This code works fine:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    afterEvaluate { project ->
        project.apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    }
}
```

gradle --init-script etc/quality.gradle sonarqube